# MY cssjson code not is not effecting my div

Tags: css, json, jsonp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/common.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() { 
     $.getJSON('http://api.jo.je/justgiving/jsonp.php?d=expedition-aconcagua&callback=?', {},  function (data) {           
            $('#title').html(data.title);          
            $('#target').html(data.donations_target);           
            $('#raised').html(data.donations_total);          
            $('#percent').html(data.percentage_complete);    
            $('#charity').html(data.charity);    
            $('#charity_details').html(data.charity_details);    
            $('#charity_logo').html(data.charity_logo);
            var donations = "";
            $.each(data.donations, function(index, value) {                         
                    if (index < 3)
                    {
                            donations  = donations + "<strong>" + value.person + "</strong>" + value.amount + "<br />" + value.message + "<br />";
                    }
            });             
            $('#donations').html(donations);

            var cssjson = {
                ".percentage_bar_complete":{
                "width":"data.percentage_complete"
                }
            }

            var styleStr = "";
            for(var i in cssjson){ styleStr += i + " {\n"
            for(var j in cssjson[i]){
            styleStr += "\t" + j + ":" + cssjson[i][j] + ";\n"     
            }
            styleStr += "}\n"  
            }
       })  
});  

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h2><span id='title'></span></h2>
    <h3><span id='charity'></span></h2>
    <div><img src="<span id='charity_logo'></span>" /><span id='charity_logo'></span></div>
    <h3>Target <span id='target'></span>, <span id='raised'></span> raised</h3>

    <h4>Percentage Complete - <span id='percent'></span>%</h4>
    <div class="percentage_bar">
        <div class="baseline">
            <p>0%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="total">
            <p>100%</p>
        </div>
        <br clear="all" />
        <div class="percentage_bar_bg">
            <div class="percentage_bar_complete">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3>Most recent donations</h3>

    <div id='donations'></div>
```

I am having difficulty getting the CSS part of the JSON to work. The intention is to have two div layers one top of the other, the bottom with a width of 100% to indicate the empty bar and the other with a percent width drawn from the JustGiving JSON feed "percentage_complete".

However the CSSJSON code I have added does not seem to working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The page as it is can be viewed here http://www.adam-poole.co.uk/test/jg.html

Comment: Hi Adam, I've the dev of api.jo.je, if you have any API related queries or functionality requests/feedback etc, please let me know! My email/twitter is on http://api.jo.je/justgiving/ or @easyjo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cssjson = {
  ".percentage_bar_complete":{
     "width":"data.percentage_complete"
  }
}
```

you are setting the width property to the value of `(string) "data.percentage_complete"` instead of the value of the variable `data.percentage_complete`. remove the double quotation marks around the variable name.

Comment: Hi Dvir, Thank you for the reply and apologies it has taken me so long to answer back. I tried removing the double quotes from the variable name but it made no difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: @ratpuddle are you sure? because I tried it myself and this fixed it. To clear up, the third line should be `"width": data.percentage_complete` instead of what it is now.

Comment: I have tried again but did remove the double quotation marks as indicated.        "width": data.percentage_complete
  I still do not seem to be geting the required result. Did you get a colour bar appear on top of the grey one?

Comment: @ratpuddle: there are two problems with it. One is the one I said, and two is - what the hell is this styleStr supposed to do? That's not the way to alter CSS properties after the DOM has loaded, and even if it was, you are still not using that variable anywhere. You need to try something like: `$(".percentage_bar_complete").css("width", data.percentage_complete + "%");` instead of this styleStr stuff.

Comment: Thank you for persevering with me. This was my first attempt CSSJSON and it would appear that I picked a bad bit of example code to work from. You were right the styleStr section and var was the problem. I removed this and added the above code and it works perfectly. Thanks again.